# Actions of amenable groups on graphs with uncountably many ends

Tags: graph-theory, geometric-group-theory, amenability

Let $G$ be a finitely generated amenable group acting transitively on an amenable Schreier graph $S$. Is it possible for $S$ to have uncountably many ends? An amenable graph with uncountably many ends might be something like a slowly growing tree. I guess the answer is positive, but I'd like to see a simple example.

Comment: Your first sentence is confusing to me: if $G$ is a group with a finite generating set and $H$ a subgroup, there is an action of $G$ on $G/H$, a ("Schreier") graph structure on $G/H$, but the action of $G$ on $G/H$ does not preserve the graph structure except in a few rare exceptions. Here are a two distinct interpretations of the question: 1) does there exist a f.g. amenable group with a Schreier graph with uncountably many ends? 2) does there exist a transitive action of a f.g. amenable group on a graph with infinitely many ends?... Could you clarify?

Comment: @YCor: I think of $S$ as being a graph with edges (and possibly loops) labelled by generators of $G$, and $G$ acting by isometries (by moving the vertices along the labelled arrows). Does that clarify what I mean here?

Comment: No, it seems you make a confusion. The action of $G$ on $G/H$ endowed with the Schreier graph metric is not by isometries in general.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, of course the action is not by isometries, I've edited the question. So the action doesn't preserve the graph structure.

Comment: How do you see that the Schreier graphs of an amenable group are amenable?

Comment: Right, $H$ doesn't have to be normal. I've edited the question.

Comment: So amenability of both the group and the Schreier graph are part of the assumptions? this sounds not very natural to me.

Comment: Why? In any case, that's what I'm assuming - both $G$ and $S$ are amenable.

Comment: Because you can artificially make the graph amenable by taking the pointed union with a bi-infinite line, adding an extra-generator $q$. Since then $[G,q]$ is contained in the set of finitely supporting permutations, you deduce that the new acting group $\langle G,q\rangle$ is amenable (if $G$ is amenable). Hence if you have an amenable group with a Schreier graph with uncountably many ends, you also get an amenable group with an amenable Schreier graph with uncountably many ends.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But still the question remains - can I have a Schreier graph with uncountably many ends to start with?

Comment: That's (finally) the question. At the moment, I only can find examples with countably (infinitely) many ends.